# Is there any possibility to get Logic App Workflow Actions name in .Net C# or using any REST API?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, workflow, azure-logic-apps

I am using the `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Logic` package to get the Azure Logic App and its related details. I need to find all the triggers and actions available in a logic app Workflow.

I could get triggers' names whereas for actions we use this method `logicManagementClient.WorkflowRunActions.List(resourceGroupName, workflowName, runName)` but this will fetch the actions of a particular run of the logic app but I need the actions of the workflow (I agree that in most cases, both actions are similar unless we edit the actions in the workflow but I don't have the value for the property "`runName`").

I have tried with this [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/logic/workflows/get?tabs=HTTP#code-try-0) but it displays the action name as a JSON property. Since it is a dynamically named property I couldn't exactly get the actions name, also the structure of the `actions` object changes according to the condition, and loops specified.

Kindly someone provide some insights on solving this!

Answer (score 1):

The REST API that you've shared is the only one that you can use. The action names are basically escaped and snake cased versions of the action names, which is the UI handles in the designer.

If you reverse that, you should get the action names.